# Were there any changes in OneDrive API response?

Tags: onedrive

It seems the response of the following OneDrive API has been changed lately.

GET /v1.0/drive/items/{item-id}
  * item-id: id of "root"

Previous response:
 The "driveItem" resource does not include "parentReference" property.

Current response:
 The "driveItem" resource includes "parenetReference" property with only "driveId" attribute.

I couldn`t find this change in the Changelog (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/changelog).

Were there any changes in OneDrive API response lately?

Answer (score 1):

This change was made available some time in June, so its been a while now. But yes, we did introduce this change mid-year.

Comment: To add to this, if you were using the lack of the parentReference property to determine if a folder was the "root" folder for a drive, you can use the presence of the "root" property now to determine that same state.